# How to change title in grafana's bar gauge panel

Tags: grafana

This is a trivial question. But i can't find an answer on it.
I have a metric in prometheus like this:

```
foo{x="0",y="0"} 10
foo{x="1",y="0"} 15
foo{x="0",y="1"} 30
foo{x="1",y="1"} 18
```

I create a bar gauge panel where in title of each bar i see ({x="0",y="0"} ; {x="1",y="0"} ; {x="0",y="1"} ; {x="1",y="1"}), but i want smth like this: 0,0 ; 1,0 ; 0,1 ; 1,1

In the tooltip for title option i see:
[Template variables: $__series_name, $__field_name, $__cell_{N} / $__calc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkYpz.png)

But can't understand how i can use it for my problem

Answer (score 5):

The template you need is `$__cell_{N}`, where `{N}` should be replaced with index number of the desired field.

In your example the correct Title would be:

```
$__cell_1, $__cell_2
```

Comment: Note that `$__cell_0` also exists. I had tried 1 and 2, but it turned out I needed 0.

Answer (score 1):

The title is set in the "Legend" data item in the "Queries" step (not in the "Graph" part):

Legend: `{{x}},{{y}}`

It seems different data sources may have different ways to set the legend, so this may work in different ways for different types of sources.